# Command line help cleanup and code generation

Tags: batch-file, command-line, sed

Need help finding some commands/tools for a bat file to automatically convert stuff line this:

```
%PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_0601.DeviceDesc%= asahci_Inst, PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_0601
%PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_0602.DeviceDesc%= asahci_Inst, PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_0602
%PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_0611.DeviceDesc%= asahci_Inst, PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_0611
%PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_0612.DeviceDesc%= asahci_Inst, PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_0612
```

To this (cleanup):

```
VEN_1B21&DEV_0601
VEN_1B21&DEV_0602
VEN_1B21&DEV_0611
VEN_1B21&DEV_0612
```

To this (insert code around, and next line):

```
devcon find * | find /i "VEN_1B21&DEV_0601" >NUL 
if /i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED
devcon find * | find /i "VEN_1B21&DEV_0602" >NUL
if /i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED
devcon find * | find /i "VEN_1B21&DEV_0611" >NUL
if /i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED
devcon find * | find /i "VEN_1B21&DEV_0612" >NUL
if /i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED
```

I have tried various tools like rxfind (zero documentation) and sed but i think i am using it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
pre='devcon find * | find \/i "'
post='" >NUL\nif \/i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED'
sed -n "s/.*\\\\\(.*\)/$pre\\1$post/p" input
```

or:

```
sed 's/.*\\\(.*\)/devcon find * | find \/i "\1" >NUL\nif \/i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED/' input
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `awk`:

```
awk -F '\' -v a="devcon find * | find /i" -v b=">NUL\nif /i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED" '{ print a, "\""$NF"\"", b }' file
```

or:

```
awk -F '\' '{ printf "devcon find * | find /i \"%s\" >NUL\nif /i %%ERRORLEVEL%% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED\n", $NF }' file
```

Results:

```
devcon find * | find /i "VEN_1B21&DEV_0601" >NUL
if /i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED
devcon find * | find /i "VEN_1B21&DEV_0602" >NUL
if /i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED
devcon find * | find /i "VEN_1B21&DEV_0611" >NUL
if /i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED
devcon find * | find /i "VEN_1B21&DEV_0612" >NUL
if /i %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set DEVICE=DETECTED
```